# jQuery ajax - no jQuery css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am trying to navigate through pages with ajax. I have a header and footer a div with id="content" between those two. What I want to do is to replace the content, in order to this I have an onclick on a button that starts the following JavaScript method:

```
$("#content").load("home.html", function() {
    });
```

Well it works, but the problem is that the stuff in home.html doesn't have the jQuery css. I tried to link it in the home.html file. It actually works then but it duplicates the footer like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8TZF.png
(I cannot post pictures, because of reputation..)

I just cannot found something on the web, probably because it's hard to describe this issue in a few words.

I hope someone can help me out. :)

Thanks.

Comment: What is "jQuery css"? Note that your home.html should be just snippet, not a entire html page, and all resources like css should be defined in parent page.

Comment: I have this: <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.css" />
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.1.min.js"></script> in my head in index.html, home.html is just <html> jQuery Mobile list </html>

Comment: you should not put `<html>` tag into home.html snippet, it's invalid because it will be nested `<html><html></html></html>` DOM tree

Comment: Oh, good to know. But it doesn't solve the problem. x_X

Answer (score 0):

When loading content from another HTML page into the current page with jQuery, I've found `$.load()` to be difficult to work with and quite inflexible at times.

Another approach is to use the `$.get()` method and parse the returned HTML, like this:

```
$.get('home.html', function(response){    
    var myHtml = $('#content', response); //get the section of HTML we want
    $('#content').html(myHtml); //load the returned content into the current page    
});
```

This doesn't work all that well if you're using the same ID for the selectors (I normally use a class) but aside from that it gives you much more control over what gets loaded.

Hope this helps.

http://api.jquery.com/get/

Comment: Sounds good, I have this code now: "$.get('home.html', function (response){
   var myHtml = $('#homecontent', response);
   $('#content').html(myHtml);
  });", when I click my button the content disappears but the home.html content won't appear. :/ Did I do some syntax mistake?

Comment: check what the response html was with firebug in the console. the value of myHtml must be null or empty which means that there is a problem with your selector for the returned html. try using classnames if you can instead of IDs, I had a little trouble using IDs with this method before.

Answer (score 0):

here is a code that works fine. I tested it right now.

```
//index.html

    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

        </head>
        <body>
            <input type="button" id ="click_me" Value="click me to show some content" ></input>
            <div id = "content">

            </div>
        </body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                $('#click_me').click(function(){

                    $('#content').load("test.html");
                });
        </script>
    </html>

//test.html
<div>

    <p>Loaded content here</p>

</div>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, but try to put a jquery object in test.html. I am sure it won't show, since I have kind of the same code.

Comment: In that case you need to declare <script> tag with jquery code for those objects that are inside test.html, inside the code for test.html.
Works quite fine.
If you need any source codes, please let me know. I will send you everything you need

Comment: Here is the example... 
http://kernel-studios.org/stackoverflow/
I did that there so you would believe me :)

Comment: Hmm.. but you didn't use jQuery buttons, right? Can you upload this file so I can try out something? When I download the page out of my browser it doesn't work. :(

Comment: Ajax wont work offline... 
I believe you need to upload it to some server, or run WAMP, XAMP, MAMP (depending on your operating system)
Here is the link
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B83aAHSWFPb2N2tkX2prSk1zUWM/edit?usp=sharing